# HTTP Error 500 when using curl in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, asp.net-web-api

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_time_limit(0);
$word = "product";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/ad63536b2f8108efe8c07295746c5a09/$word/json"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$bigarray = array();

if ($info['http_code'] == 200) { 
  $result = json_decode($data, true); 
  $final = json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  file_put_contents("results.json", $final);
    $bigarray = $result["noun"]["syn"];

  }



 else echo "Http Error: ".$info['http_code'];

foreach ($bigarray as $value) {
echo $value."<br>";
}   
?>
```

this code displays the synonyms of $word variable.when executing on xampp gives http error 500, worked fine before but now this error emerged

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status code 500 means in this case, that the API key is no longer valid or is an inactive key.

Use proper authentication against this API, before or with the request.

Requesting an API key is described over here: https://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php